# Dollar Object intricacies

Tags: c#, tdd, assertions

I am reading Kent Beck's book "Test Driven Development: By Example." In his book, there is a coding example:

```
public class Dollar
{
    public int _amount;
    public Dollar(int amount)
    {
        _amount = amount;
    }
    public Dollar Times(int multiplier)
    {
        return new Dollar(_amount *= multiplier);
    }
}

[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod2()
{                        
    Dollar five = new Dollar(5);
    Dollar product = five.Times(2);
    Assert.AreEqual(10, product._amount);
    product = five.Times(3);
    Assert.AreEqual(15, product._amount);
}
```

According to Kent, a second Dollar object: "product," is necessary in order to preserve the original "five" dollar object; however, the second assertion returns false because product._amount is equal to 30. I have been unable to find any errata on this text. How would Kent's code above need to change in order to have the second assertion equal true or 15 == 15? Is the book's example flawed? Why does product._amount in the second assertion not equal 15?

Comment: `_amount *= multiplier` is very wrong.

Comment: There's a typing error on my part: (_amount *= multiplier) should be (_amount * multiplier). Thanks SLaks

Comment: Are you sure you're not doing `product.Times(3)`? I can't see how you can get 30.

Comment: I'm assuming the *= was also in your code, because that would make the `product` come out to 30...

Comment: It was in an earlier version of Kent's code; however, further down within the code he uses only the *

Comment: @DannyBaker I've added a CW answer, as your problem seems to have been solved, by the comments above.  If this is correct, you can tick the check next to the answer to accept it.  If your problem still exists, can you edit your question to clarify what is still outstanding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As has been said in the comments, this:

```
public Dollar Times(int multiplier) {
    return new Dollar(_amount *= multiplier);
}
```

Should be:

```
public Dollar Times(int multiplier) {
    return new Dollar(_amount * multiplier);
}
```

In its original form, the `*=` operator modifies the `_amount` variable of the instance of the `Dollar` class that `Times` is called on.  Removing the `=` changes the operation so that it only reads the value of the `_amount` variable and uses it in the calculation.